# DataRow throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, dataset

This is my code:

```
 private string[] quizList;

 public string[] getQuizList() 
 {    
     Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter ta = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter();
     Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizDataTable table = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizDataTable();
     ta.Fill(table);

     System.Data.DataRow[] row = table.Select("id > 0");

     for(int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)    
         quizList[i] = row[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();

     return quizList;
 }
```

When I am debugging I can see the table is filled with data and row is also filled with data. But when it comes to the for loop, it always throwing null reference exception. What is the wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain there are three items per row?

Comment: @Oded Yes I am sure. The items are id, course and name. In the debugging window also it shows 3 items.

Comment: Any reason you're declaring `quizList` outside your method? Also why don't you get the cell value via column name like `row[i]["name"].ToString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside method initialize `quizList`

```
quizList = new string[row.Length];
```

and then run loop.

Inside loop quizList is null and you are trying to access an index of it.

So your function should be like

```
 private string[] quizList;

 public string[] getQuizList() 
 {    
     Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter ta = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter();
     Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizDataTable table = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizDataTable();
     ta.Fill(table);

     System.Data.DataRow[] row = table.Select("id > 0");

     quizList = new string[row.Length];

     for(int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)    
         quizList[i] = row[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();

     return quizList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that `quizList` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an index of the quizList before it is initialized. Try doing something like this:

```
quizList = new String[row.length];
```

before you use it.